# Footer is not visible on Safari in Mac

Tags: html, css, safari, footer

I have been working on a website where I need to show a sticky footer. I could make it and it is working fine in other browsers but not in Safari. The footer is not visible in Safari. Below is my HTML and CSS for the footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.footer{
  background-image: url(../images/footer_bck.png);
  height: 23em;
  min-width: 980px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.footer_logo{

position: relative;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: 45%;
margin-top: 2%;


}

.footer_line{
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.footer_list li{
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 66px;
  padding-top: 10px;

}
.footer_list li a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "museo_sans900";
}
.footer-text h4{
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
margin-left: 85px;
margin-top: -3%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
.......
  <footer class="footer large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
      <img class="footer_logo" src="images/footer_webable.png">
      <img class="footer_line" src="images/footer_line.png">

      <div>
        <h4>
        <ul class="footer_list large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The Bable blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>

        </ul>
        </h4>

        <div class="footer-text large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns"><h4>2015 Webable Digital. All Rights Reserved.</h4></div> 
      </div>


    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to figure it out why the footer is not at all visible in safari.

Comment: check your browser console. go through the DOM and see where the footer is actually located in page.